# Is there a formal definition of "continuous at a point for all practical purposes" or "continuous at a point within a given tolerance"?

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, approximation, computational-mathematics

Consider a function $f\colon D \to \mathbf{R}$ such that at some inner point $a$ of its domain $D\subseteq \mathbf{R}$
$$\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = L, \qquad \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) =R, \qquad L \ne R \ ,$$
and the value $f(a)$ may be equal to either limit or have a yet different value.

Obviously the function isn't continuous at $a$.

But suppose that we are studying it with some numerical method, and the difference between $L$, $R$, and $f(a)$ is less than the precision used in the method. Say, for example, that $R=2+ \mathrm{e}^{-1000}$ and $L=2$. From the point of view of the numerical method the function can, so to speak, be considered continuous at $a$. A similar situation can arise with functions meant to fit empirical data.

Is there some notion of "approximate continuity at $a$" that applies in this case? An intuitive definition would be something like $\lvert \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) - \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)  \rvert <\delta$ and $\lvert \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) - f(a) \rvert <\delta$ and so on, for some tolerance $\delta>0$. But I have no idea whether some definition of this kind is used in computational mathematics and how it is formally called.

I'd be thankful for any references you know of about some notion similar to this.

Note: The expression "approximate continuity" I use here has nothing to do with the definition of [approximate continuity](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Approximate_continuity) connected with measure theory, of course; but I couldn't find a better expression. Also, I'm aware that in [computable analysis](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Computable_function) all computable functions are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the oscillation of a function at a point as follows:

Let $f: I \to \Bbb R$ be a bounded function where $I \subset \Bbb R$. Let $a \in I$. Then, for $\delta > 0$, define

$$M(f, a, \delta) = \sup_{|x - a| < \delta}f(x) \quad\text{and}\quad m(f, a, \delta) = \inf_{|x - a| < \delta}f(x).$$

Then, the oscillation is defined as $$o(f, a) := \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}[M(f, a, \delta) - m(f, a, \delta)].$$

(This limit must exist. Why?)

Note that $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $o(f, a) = 0$. Now, for your purpose, you can define "continuous within tolerance $\epsilon$" by saying that "$o(f, a) < \epsilon$ for all $a \in I$."

---

Edit: If you don't particularly care about the value of the function at $a$ itself, you can modify the definitions of $M$ and $m$ to take the $\sup$/$\inf$ over those $x$ such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.

Comment: Great, thank you, I didn't know about this definition. Could you add some reference so I can explore more?

Comment: @pglpm: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)). I had first come across it in Spivak's book "Calculus on Manifolds". This quantity was useful in determining existence integrals.

Comment: Thank you. Luckily the wikipedia article seems to give two references (it not always does!)

Answer (score 1):

So in engineering and applied mathematics, when two functions $f,g$ are equal in all but a finite number of points, it makes some sense to consider them the same function. In other words, almost everywhere (a.e.) equality is *good enough*. A more technical way of saying this is that in engineering fields, engineers and researchers like to work with functions modulo a.e. equality.

This is due to a lot of good reasons. First, the derivatives of $f,g$ are also a.e. equal. Most importantly, $\|f-g\|^2=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx=0$. this nicely implies that $f,g$ share the same Fourier series. It follows from these properties many real analysis theorems for functions hold when you use a.e. equality instead of equality. I mean think about it, they are the same thing except at this 1 infinitesimally tiny point. Other than that one point, the information of the function is fixed. Your line of thinking is correct.

There are definitely generalizations of continuity for a.e. equal functions. One example is piecewise continuity.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense indeed. I was wondering if it had been formalized and given a formal name. I call that "approximately continuous" but that's a bad term since it's already used for something different. Piecewise continuity would indicate a different situation: we would say it's piecewise continuous if the "pieces" didn't join within the given tolerance, and (practically) continuous if they did join within that tolerance.

Comment: Just say that the left and right limits must agree at every point. This means a continuous function with a finite number of points removed will be “approximately continuous”

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I see now that my post is not clear, will try to fix that. The case I have in mind is when the left and right limit are different, but "almost equal" within some tolerance.

Comment: @pglpm Ah I see. Very interesting. Perhaps $f$ is $\delta$-almost continuous if it is continuous at all but finite points $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^n$, and we have the property that the left and right limits at any x_j are within $\delta$ of each other? We can go one step further and say that a function is simply $\delta$-almost continuous if (1) the left and right limits, $l$ and $r$, exist at every poin; and (2) $|l-r|<\delta$?

Comment: The notion of "oscillation" (a somewhat misleading name for this specific use) referred to in Aryaman's answer seems to fit this idea of "approximate continuity" well.